# Bott Chern cohomology via currents

Tags: complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold. Is the space of $(p,p)$ $d$-closed currents modulo $\partial\bar{\partial}$-exact ones naturally isomorphic to the Bott-Chern cohomology (made in the same way with smooth forms)? I can prove this statement for $p=1$ or for any $p$ on Kähler manifolds (via the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma for currents), but I can not prove it for $p > 1$ on a general manifold. Does anyone know how to prove it?

Comment: When $\partial\bar\partial$ lemma holds, Bott Chern cohomology and Dolbeault cohomology are the same, what is the your exact question?

Comment: @HassanJolany I think, we wants to see what happens for general complex manifolds.

Answer (score 11):

When $X$ is a compact complex manifold, its Bott-Chern cohomology groups can be computed either by smooth forms or by currents. The proof of this fact can be found for instance in Demailly's book (link [here](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf)), page 326, considerations after the proof of Lemma 12.2.

Demailly derives there this result from hypercohomological considerations.

Answer (score 6):

This is a theorem which was first proved by Bruno Bigolin in [this paper:](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASNSP_1970_3_24_3_571_0)

Osservazioni sulla coomologia del $\partial \overline{\partial}$, Annali della Scuola Normale Superiore di Pisa - Classe di Scienze, Sér. 3, 24 no. 3 (1970), 571-583,

stated there as Proposition 2.2. The argument is pretty much the same as the one in Demailly's book that diverietti mentions.